# How do I solve this integral with Gamma (probably) or beta functions?

Tags: integration, gamma-function, beta-function

$$\iint\cdots\int_{\mathbb R^n}\left(\prod_{i=1}^n x_i^m\frac{e^{-x_i^2}}{e^\frac{x_i}{2}\cosh\left(\frac{x_i}{2}\right)}\right)d^nx$$

I have managed to bring it to a form where the elements of the gamma function appear but there are more terms that don't allow it to turn into said gamma function.
$$\prod_{i=1}^n \int\left(\ x_i^m\frac{e^{-x_i^2}}{e^\frac{x_i}{2}\cosh\left(\frac{x_i}{2}\right)}\right)dx_i$$
so the product of the independent

$$ \int\ 2x^m\frac{e^{-x^2}}{e^x + 1}dx\ $$
I just don't know how to shake the $e^x + 1$

---

So...what I ended up with is
$$ \sum_{n=0}^∞\sum_{k=0}^∞\ [\frac{(-1)^{n+k}*(m+2k)!}{k!}*[\frac{(-1)^m}{n^{m+2k+1}} +\frac{1}{(n+1)^{m+2k+1}}]]\ $$

Comment: Please use mathjax for your equations. As for the integral, I doubt it can be evaluated in closed form.

Comment: For the last integral, consider breaking the intervals into $\int_{-\infty}^0$ and $\int_0^\infty$. Then use the fact that $(1-z)^{-1}=1+z+z^2+\cdots$ when $|z|<1$.

Comment: That still doesn't bring it to a compatible form to solve with a gamma function

Comment: edit: I expressed $$ e^{x^2} $$ as a sum and got a known integral for the (-infinity, 0) part
it's still a double sum (not pretty) but I guess ok
the other one is the problem now

Comment: the same double same can be derived from the second 
the only difference between the two is a $$ (-1)^m $$ in the first and the denominators $$ n^{m+2k+1} $$ in the first and $$ (n+1)^{m+2k+1} $$ in the second